# integrating paypal with a single page web app on IPAD-safari, communicating between tabs

Tags: ipad, paypal

i have a web app on html5 and running on a single page, lots of Ajax and javascript, so everything takes place on a single page.

Payment takes place with paypal digital good express which on desktop opens on the same tab without opening a separate page. It all works great on desktop, running all on 1 single html5 page.

On iPAD the problem is that paypal digital goods express opens on a separate tab. And i need to find a way to communicate after payment with the previous tab where the app is running.
Because after successful payment the single page web app immediately runs a new key process.
On iPAD i cannot start that process because paypal opens on a separate tab and once payment completes successfully there , i dont know how to send a signal to the javascript code of the previous tab.

I guess the main tab of the web app could be polling the server for news, but that seems rather inefficient considering how easy it is on desktop

i appreciate very much any help :)